# Didn't catch any exception while the key is incorrect in decryption AES

Tags: encryption, aes

I use AES encryption/decryption to retrieve data and decrypt. I use an incorrect key for decryption and I didn't get any error or exception I get a sentence with strange language like this:

> "0??0??YP?*:$Y???S?n?"

How can I get an exception when the decryption is incorrect. I put many exception like CryptoTokenException, CryptoUnsupportedOperationException, UnsupportedEncodingException and I didn't catch any exception.

What can I do to? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Where's your code & runtime? What is the mode of operation (e.g. ECB, CBC, CTR) that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some integrity check to be sure that it was correctly encrypted, transmitted and decrypted. The integrity check also be manipulated which is why it must be *authenticated*. AES itself and some modes of operation like CBC don't have a facility for integrity checks. If the ciphertext was changed somehow, most of the time you can decrypt it without problems, but the resulting plaintext is broken. There are some cases when the end of the ciphertext is manipulated which might trigger a padding exception.

Crypto.SE has some material on this: [Should we MAC-then-encrypt or encrypt-then-MAC?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac) The easiest and safest would be to use some authenticated cipher modes like GCM or CCM, because rolling your own crypto is always not a good idea. You could introduce implementation flaws which break the scheme.